# How do I move my ubuntu files to my SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, transfer

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04. unfortunately, it refused to allow me to install it on my SSD(the same one my windows is on) and only allowed me to do it on my HDD. By that I mean it wasn't on the list for some absurd reason. I'm trying to figure out how to move it to my SSD. I'm new to Linux, so just explain it to me like I'm 5. I want to move it to my SSD bc it's faster btw.

Comment: If you can't figure out why you couldn't install Ubuntu in your SSD, then you can't install Ubuntu in the SSD. Moving the system partition of Ubuntu from HDD to SSD is not easy. It is not for 5 to 75 year olds. I would do a full install from scratch in the SSD.

Comment: do you have any idea how i could atleast try to copy the partition and move it over?

Comment: Did you turn off bitlocker & Windows fast start up in Windows? Otherwise Linux cannot see the Windows drive. New versions now do not need change to AHCI driver as they can use the vmd driver for NVMe drives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) The "Something else" option of the Ubuntu installer will allow you to select the SSD, manually partition the SSD, and install Ubuntu on it